# Accessing lists of other agents

Tags: netlogo

I have two lists that all agents make.  I would like that one agent looks at the agents to see whether his agent number is in the list of the other agent.  If he finds his number in the list of the other agent, he has to copy the number of that other agent. How?

```
if attracted != nobody [set attractinglists fput ([who] of attracted) attractinglists]

if attracted != nobody [set attrlists fput ([who] of attracting) attrlists]

to-report contains-any?
let attrlistss [attrlists] of myself
if attractinglists != nobody [foreach attractinglists [if member? ? attrlistss [report true]] report false]
end

let lisstt list self contains-any?
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like each turtle wants a list of other turtles that have that one turtle's id in the list of turtles they are attracted to.  Here's a simple model that might prove a guide for you.  In general you should not use who numbers and this model does not.

```
turtles-own [
  attracted-to
  attracted-to-me
]

to setup
clear-all
reset-ticks
create-turtles 100 
ask turtles [
  ; each turtle picks 20 random turtles to be attracted to.
  set attracted-to n-of 20 other turtles
]
end

to go
ask turtles [
  set attracted-to-me [self] of other turtles with [member? myself attracted-to]
]
ask turtles [show attracted-to-me]
end
```

Hope this helps.